# Ubuntu Server: How to make bootable bios_grub RAID device?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, raid, mdadm

I have a stable Ubuntu (14.04.3) Server-powered file server that I have set up, and want to set up a RAID10 array for it. For reference, I have been following [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/software-raid1-grub-boot-debian-etch) so far, but using RAID10 instead of RAID1.

My main goal is to make the system able to boot even if the bios_grub RAID devcice becomes degraded / a drive fails / etc.

I have 4 identical drives, with only one in use currently (/dev/sda). It has the following partition table:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                        bios_grub
 2      2097kB  2984GB  2984GB  ext4
 3      2984GB  3001GB  16.9GB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Identical drives sdb, sdc, and sdd have had the partition table of sda copied to each of them, using sgdisk. I am now at the point of assembling my RAID devices.

I want to create:

1. /dev/md0, consisting of /dev/sda1, /dev/sdb1, /dev/sdc1, and /dev/sdd1
2. /dev/md1, consisting of /dev/sda2, /dev/sdb2, /dev/sdc2, and /dev/sdd2
3. /dev/md2, consisting of /dev/sda3, /dev/sdb3, /dev/sdc3, and /dev/sdd3

with all /mdX being of type RAID10. /dev/md1 and /dev/md2 will be created using:

```
sudo mdadm --create   /dev/mdX --chunk=256 --level=10 -p f2 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdaX /dev/sdbX /dev/sdcX /dev/sddX
```

From what I've gathered, my /dev/md0 array should be created using:

```
sudo mdadm --create -e 0.90 /dev/md0 --chunk=256 --level=10 -p f2 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1  /dev/sdd1
```

using the v0.90 metadata, for better compatibility with GRUB.

I know that I need to create filesystems for each /mdX, before I can mount them, or try to reboot. The swap device should be done using:

```
sudo mkswap /dev/md2
```

and the main storage device (/md1) should be done using

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/md1
```

My question(s) are these:

1. What "filesystem" do I need to create for /dev/md0, or do I even need to do anything else? Most guides I see use a separate /boot partition, but I just have my bios_grub partition.
2. What else do I need to do to install GRUB correctly, so that the system can boot from any of the drives? If a drive fails or is physically removed from the machine, I still want the system to be able to boot.

I know I still need to edit my /etc/mtab and /etc/fstab files, but want to get the correct GRUB setup before proceeding with creating these arrays (ie, while I know my system will still boot!)

Thanks for the help!